# Bidirectionally bind to property negation

Tags: java, data-binding, javafx, 2-way-object-databinding, property-binding

Given

```
DoubleProperty A;
DoubleProperty minusA;
```

is there a way to bind their negations bidirectionally to each other, so that A.get() == -minusA.get() at all times, and both can be `set()`?

Answer (score 0):

I tried but did´t find a way by using a bidirectional binding but maybe you could use an InvalidationListner on both?

Something like

```
A.addListener((Observable observable) -> {
        System.out.println("A is invalid");
        minusA.set(A.get() *-1);
    });

minusA.addListener((Observable observable) -> {
        System.out.println("minusA is invalid");
        A.set(minusA.get() * -1);
    });
```

then you could easily call the setter method of both DoubleProperties and the other value will change to the negativ value.

Hope that helps